# Tracking DNT Exception handling

Tags: javascript, exception, tracking, privacy, do-not-track

Currently Im trying to solve a problem about tracking.

On our website, an user should be able to decide whether or not he gets tracked and also which kind of information is shared.

Also we have different third party tracking mechanism, which can be switched off aswell. (if the user wants to)

I resolved this problem with local storage + cookies. If the user decides to deactivate one of our trackings, the code which is responsible for that kind of tracking will not be transmitted via the requested file.

Also I do respect the settings from `window.Navigator.doNotTrack`, which will in case of beeing 1, resolve in a snackbar popping up and asking for permission.

All Information I found about this topic is [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/tracking-dnt/#exceptions)

What I want to know is how to ask for an exception and also how to see whether or not the website is accepted or not.

I tried what is described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/tracking-dnt/#dom-navigator-storetrackingexception) but it does not seem to work.

```
Navigator.trackingExceptionExists // will be undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***DNT*** header field is a mechanism for expressing the user's tracking preference in an HTTP request. At most one *DNT* header field can be present in a valid request.

> DNT-field-name  = *"DNT"*
>
> DNT-field-value = ("0" / "1") **DNT-extension*

- A user agent **MUST NOT** generate a *DNT* header field if the user's
  tracking preference is *not enabled*.
- A user agent **MUST** generate a DNT header field with a field-value
  that begins with the numeric character **"1"** if the user's tracking
  preference is enabled, their preference is for ***DNT:1***, and no
  exception has been granted for the request target.
- A user agent MUST generate a DNT header field with a field-value that
  begins with the numeric character **"0"** if the user's tracking
  preference is enabled and their preference is for ***DNT:0***, or if an
  exception has been granted for the request target.
- A ***proxy MUST NOT*** generate a DNT header field unless it has been
  specifically installed or configured to do so by the user making the
  request and adheres to the above requirements as if it were a user
  agent.

Here are some *Methods* to Request a Site-specific Exception:

> 1. **void storeSiteSpecificTrackingException (StoreSiteSpecificExceptionPropertyBag properties)**
>
>    > This is called by a page to *store* a site-specific tracking exception. The `storeSiteSpecificTrackingException` method takes a dictionary argument of type *StoreSiteSpecificExceptionPropertyBag* that allows optional information to be provided.
> 2. **DOMString? domain**
>
>    > This is a *cookie-domain* to which the exception applies.
> 3. **DOMString? siteName**
>
>    > A user-readable string for the name of the top-level origin.
> 4. **DOMString? explanationString**
>
>    > A *short explanation* of the request.
> 5. **DOMString? detailURI**
>
>    > A *location* at which further information about this request can be found.
> 6. **DOMString? expires**
>
>    > A date and time, encoded as described for the *cookie expires* attribute indicating the *maximum lifetime* of the remembered grant.
> 7. **long? maxAge**
>
>    > A positive number of seconds indicating the *maximum lifetime* of the remembered grant.
> 8. **sequence arrayOfDomainStrings**
>
>    > A JavaScript array of strings. If the request does not include the `arrayOfDomainStrings`, then this request is for a ***site-wide*** exception. Otherwise each string in *arrayOfDomainStrings* specifies a target. When called, `storeSiteSpecificTrackingException` **MUST** return immediately. If the list *arrayOfDomainStrings* is supplied, the user agent MAY choose to store a site-wide exception. If it does so it MUST indicate this in the return value.

So, as an answer to your first question ***how to ask for an exception ?***, I would suggest you to do this :

```
Navigator.storeSiteSpecificTrackingException
```

And if you would like to remove the permission grants, then do this:

```
Navigator.removeSiteSpecificTrackingException
```

> There is no callback for `removeSiteSpecificTrackingException`. After the call has been made, it is assured that there are *no site-specific or site-wide exceptions for the given top-level origin*.

And as an answer to your second question ***how to see whether or not the exception preferences on a website is accepted or not ?***, `confirmSiteSpecificTrackingException` is a method used for the same:

```
boolean confirmSiteSpecificTrackingException (ConfirmSiteSpecificExceptionPropertyBag properties)
```

> This method is called by a page to confirm a site-specific tracking exception.

So all that you have to do is:

```
Navigator.confirmSiteSpecificTrackingException
```

Comment: It looks like this is only supported by IE, isnt it? I cannot find a way to archieve this in google chrome or firefox.

Comment: I am afraid so. I could not find anything in order to achieve the same on chrome or firefox.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
navigator.confirmSiteSpecificTrackingException
```

Check the below link for complete reference

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265021(v=vs.85).aspx